# Node.js installation: openssl not installed

Tags: javascript, ssl, ubuntu, node.js, openssl

I have installed libssl-dev and openssl but I get this when I install node.js:

```
> ./configure && make && make install                                                                                          
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++                                                                                                               
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp                                                                                                               
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar                                                                                                                
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib                                                                                                            
Checking for g++                         : ok                                                                                                                         
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc                                                                                                               
Checking for gcc                         : ok                                                                                                                         
Checking for library dl                  : yes                                                                                                                        
Checking for openssl                     : not found                                                                                                                  
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : yes                                                                                                                        
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : yes                                                                                                                        
Checking for library rt                  : yes                                                                                                                        
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : yes
```

Openssl is not found. But node was installed successfully.

Why isn't openssl found? Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Short answer: install pkg-config. I just spent half a day installing node & npm on a server to which I don't have root access.  Long story short, build openssl & pkg-config from source into a local directory FIRST and node & npm will build just fine.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This isn't exactly a programming question.  Still...

### Quick answer

The installer checks for OpenSSL support in two ways.  The first check failed for you, the second succeeded.  For me, the first check succeeded (see below).  Either way works.

### Longer answer

Here's what I got when I built it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : yes 
<---snip--->
```

Presuming you downloaded [node.js v0.2.3](http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.2.3.tar.gz) from http://nodejs.org/, the configuration is mostly done by [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) in the file wscript.

The relevant lines are:

```
  if not Options.options.without_ssl:
    if conf.check_cfg(package='openssl',
                      args='--cflags --libs',
                      uselib_store='OPENSSL'):
      Options.options.use_openssl = conf.env["USE_OPENSSL"] = True
      conf.env.append_value("CPPFLAGS", "-DHAVE_OPENSSL=1")
    else:
      libssl = conf.check_cc(lib='ssl',
                             header_name='openssl/ssl.h',
                             function_name='SSL_library_init',
                             libpath=['/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/opt/local/lib', '/usr/sfw/lib'],
                             uselib_store='OPENSSL')
      libcrypto = conf.check_cc(lib='crypto',
                                header_name='openssl/crypto.h',
                                uselib_store='OPENSSL')
```

The first part is simple enough.  It runs pkgconfig.  Here is what happens when I do the equivalent by hand:

```
 $ pkg-config openssl --cflags --libs
 -lssl -lcrypto
```

The second set of checks is run if pkg-config fails to confirm the package is installed.  In that case, it tries to compile a trivial gcc program which checks for the existence of functions in libcrypt and libssl.  If those both succeed, installation continues.  If one of them fails, there's a fatal error, and the script bombs out.

Comment: Okay, but the problem is why doesn't node find my openssl. I have it installed by "aptitude install libssl-dev openssl".

Comment: @weng That aspect of your question is not programming related, and if that's what you're concerned about rather than understanding the programming behind it, you should ask on ServerFault.  As I indicated in my answer, the problem is pkg-config doesn't thing openssl is there.  If you run 'pkg-config openssl || echo "No OpenSSL"' you should see this.  See 'man pkg-config' on how to construct a .pc file to tell pkg-config a package is installed.

Comment: sudo apt-get install pkg-config

Answer (score 49):

@weng: I had the same problem. The solution was easy: sudo apt-get install pkg-config :)

Comment: So, what is the procedure?  run sun apt-get install pkg-config first?

Comment: Yup, that fixed it for me too.  The wscript file uses pkg-config to check for openssl. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/11668

Comment: Fixed it for me.  I also had to do an apt-get update first.  Compiled and used node in April 2011 no problem, but it seems like something cropped up in the mean time.

Answer (score 26):

I Had the same problem using Debian 6. I had to install libcurl4-openssl-dev.

Switch to root user, or use sudo, then run:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me when installing node on a new machine (Ubuntu 11.04) where the solution above (sudo apt-get install pkg-config) didn't.

Comment: This fixed the problem on Ubuntu

Comment: Worked for me too! Ubuntu server 11.04

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 10.04 with nodejs 0.6.1

Comment: If this worked for you, you did not have the same problem as is asked in the original question.  The user *had* openssl installed, but not pkg-config (or pkg-config didn't know about the openssl package).  If you look at your installation messages,you will find you got `Checking for function SSL_library_init   : no `.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Conspicuous Compiler! Here was my thought process on this. I was seeing the same output from the question above.  I tried installing pkg-config but no luck.  I read over your "long answer" and eventually was able to use it to help track down my real problem... I didn't have the correct openssl development libraries installed.  Hopefully this will others who have traveled down the same road I did.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 11.10 and nodejs 0.6.11!

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise) and nodejs v0.6.19!

Answer (score 10):

If using Centos 5.x, make sure that you install openssl-devel prior to ./configure.

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

This solved the same issue for me in centos.

Answer (score 3):

1. confirm your openssl installed.
2. if installed, confirm its path in `['/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/opt/local/lib', '/usr/sfw/lib']`;
3. if not in those paths, try following options with your correct openssl path
   `./configure --openssl-libpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib --openssl-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include`

Answer (score 3):

Seems like I can do:

```
apt-get install lib32z1-dev
apt-get install pkg-config
```

to consistently remove all errors and warnings about openssl when I'm doing a fresh Rackspace deployment with Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10, in case that helps anyone else out.

Here's a gist with a rundown of the script I finally settled on for spinning up these types of instances with node.js:

https://gist.github.com/1606102

**Edit**: Updated the gist to reflect the updates made to Node, etc.

Comment: What are these libraries used for in this instance?

Comment: Hey Mr. A.  lib32z1-dev is a zlib compression library (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/lib32z1-dev) and pkg-config is used to retrieve information about libraries installed on your system (http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config)

Comment: in my case, `sudo apt-get install pkg-config` solved the openssl not found warning

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I tried

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/node --openssl-libpath=/usr/local/lib/
```

which solved it even though I think `--openssl-libpath=/usr/local/lib/` isn`t necessary

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
apt-get install pkg-config -y
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils

Comment: Sure that apache2-utils are required?

Answer (score 1):

For people with a new Debian 6.0 (to be more precise: Debian 6.0.2.1 i386) set up, the following packages need to be installed to run node.js v.0.6.15 (latest stable at the moment):
- build-essentials
- pkg-config
- libssl-dev

Just use aptitude -y install "package" ... hope that helps for all you Debian guys. :)